# Angular 6 Object

Tags: angular

I have  with data attribute in Angular 6 project and I need to assign a value from ts file, could you please advise ?

```js
............
export class IframeComponent implements OnInit {

  XXXXXXXXXX: string = 'https://accept.payables.com/api/acceptance/iframes/4652';

  constructor(private paymentservice: PaymentService) { }
  
  ..........
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" class="text-center"> 
  <object type="text/html" data={{XXXXXXXXXX}} width="100%" height="800px" style="overflow:auto;border:5
  1px ridge white">
  </object>
```

Comment: `Object` is a your component?

Comment: no, I am trying to use object to show external http inside my project like this

Comment: <div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
 </div>

Comment: Mh, you could use an iFrame

Comment: could u please provide example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data binding:

```
  <object type="text/html" [data]="XXXXXXXXXX" width="100%" height="800px" style="overflow:auto;border:5
      1px ridge white">
```

and put the iframe as child component in the `<object>` or just use the iframe directly:

```
   <iframe [src]="XXXXXXXXXX" width="100%" height="800px">
```

Comment: this works but why it's blinking !!!
<iframe [src]='bypassandtrust()' width="100%" height="800px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" application="yes">
</iframe>

  bypassandtrust(): SafeUrl{
    this.trustedDashboardUrl =
                        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.paymenttoken);
    return this.trustedDashboardUrl;
  }